# Copy KeyBoard Wrong

Tags: android, custom-keyboard

I an  copy keyboardView from android source , but the source cannot get the xml tag Value 
the source is

```
    private void parseKeyboardAttributes(Resources res, XmlResourceParser parser) {
        //attributeSet.getAttributeCount();  = 2 
        AttributeSet attributeSet = Xml.asAttributeSet(parser);
        // but   a.getIndexCount();  = 0 
        // why? i do not know 
        TypedArray a = res.obtainAttributes(attributeSet,
               R.styleable.QmKeyboard);

        mDefaultWidth = getDimensionOrFraction(a,
               R.styleable.QmKeyboard_keyWidth,
                mDisplayWidth, mDisplayWidth / 10);
// cannot get this 
        mDefaultHeight = getDimensionOrFraction(a,
               R.styleable.QmKeyboard_qmKeyHeight,
                mDisplayHeight, 50);
```

my xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<QmKeyboard xmlns:app="http://schemas.app.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:keyHeight="51dp"
    app:keyWidth="33.0%p">
    <Row>
        <Key
            app:codes="49"
            app:keyLabel="1" />
        <Key
            app:codes="50"
            app:keyLabel="2" />
        <Key
            app:codes="51"
            app:keyLabel="3" />
    </Row>
    // ignore...
</QmKeyboard>
```

[https://github.com/guduwangwei/QmKeyboardView][github]

any body help me thanks

Comment: sorry first use stackflow link is wrong corrent is  https://github.com/guduwangwei/QmKeyboardView

Comment: Looks like `QmKeyboard_qmKeyHeight` is misspelled

Comment: i try `app:QmKeyboard_qmkeyHeight="51dp">` or `qmKeyHeight` also not work

Comment: already resolve change keyboard  Stye                                                                   **<declare-styleable name="CKeyBoard">
        <attr name="cKeyWidth" format="dimension|fraction"/>
        <attr name="cKeyHeight" format="dimension|fraction" />
        <attr name="CHorizontalGap" format="dimension|fraction" />
        <attr name="CVerticalGap" format="dimension|fraction" />
    </declare-styleable>**